# Duvida de como usar o IF em uma TRIGGER no mysql

Tags: mysql, if, tabela-html, trigger

Olá! O meu problema é o seguinte eu tenho duas tabelas, uma tabela chamada **notas** e outra chamada **alunos**. Preciso fazer uma comparação com o *id_aluno* na tabela **notas** e os *id* presentes na tabela **alunos** para somente se o *id* existir na tabela **alunos** poder inserir o valor *nota* na tabela **notas**. Gostaria de saber como poderia fazer isso.

Comment: Bruno, bem vindo ao Soft, acesse a Ajuda e faça o Tour, depois edite sua pergunta mostrando parte do seu código,

Answer (score 1):

As triggers do MySQL não permitem que seja abortado um INSERT, como em outros SGBD como o PostgreSQL.

O que você pode fazer é verificar com uma trigger AFTER INSERT (disparada após inserir a linha) se o código do aluno inserido é valido, e caso não seja pode efetuar um DELETE (é necessário uma chave primária para efetuar este DELETE com segurança).

Por exemplo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_insert_notas 
AFTER INSERT ON notas
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE aluno_existe BOOLEAN;

    SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM alunos WHERE alunos.id = NEW.id_aluno) INTO aluno_existe;

    IF NOT aluno_existe THEN
        DELETE FROM notas WHERE notas.id = NEW.id;
    END IF;
END//
```